# Styling all my buttons using CSS in GWT

Tags: css

My app will have a significant number of buttons which I want styled in a similar way.  So I use CSS for this.  Problem I see is I will have to have a line of code for each button stating the style name I want to use. To avoid this repetitive code could I instead have my own BaseButton which extends Button and apply the style to it and have all my buttons then extend this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the built in Button class as your basebutton, you can put this in CSS:

```
.gwt-Button {
   /*your style here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="button"] { 
          css code here
}
```